# Derive taylor series of $e^{\sin(x)}$ in two different ways

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

I need to find the Taylor series of $e^{\sin(x)}$ up to $x^4$ in two different ways. First I derived it by calculating the derivatives of the function, and I found the answer $P_4(x) = 1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{8}$. Now I need to use the Taylor series of $e^y$ and plug in the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ to find an answer. After that I need to draw a conclusion. So I know the Taylor series of $e^y$ up to $y^4$ looks like $P_4(y) = 1 + y + \frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{y^3}{6} + \frac{y^4}{24}$ and the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ up to $x^4$ looks like $P_4(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6}$. I substituted the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ into the $y$ variable of the Taylor series of $e^y$, but it doesn't give me the same answer as the answer I got by using the first four derivates of $e^{\sin(x)}$. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

After computing$$1+\left(x-\frac{x^3}6\right)+\frac12\left(x-\frac{x^3}6\right)^2+\frac16\left(x-\frac{x^3}6\right)^3+\frac1{24}\left(x-\frac{x^3}6\right)^4$$you must eliminate the monomials whose degree is greater than $4$. And *then* you will get the same answer as before.

Comment: Thanks! So the conclusion I can draw is that both answers are the same?

Comment: Well, you can conclude that they are the same *in this case*. And, yes, they will always be the same.

Comment: Okay, so I got the same answer after eliminating the monomials greater than 4. But now I am wondering if my notation of substituting the Taylor series of $\sin x$ for $y$ in the Taylor series of e$^y$ is correct. Do I write $P_4(x- \frac{x^3}{3!}) = ...$ in my final answer or do I write $P_4(x) = ...$ in my final answer?

Comment: @Neri Your notation $P_4$ is not well defined. If $P_4, Q_4, R_4$ are the 4-degree-Taylor-expanstions for $\sin$, $\exp$ and $\exp \circ \sin$ respectively, then you should write $P_4(x) = x - x^3$, and-$R_4(x) = Q_4(x - x^3/3!!$ (up to degree 4).

Comment: @preferred_anon Neri hasn't been seen around in a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Let $e^{\sin x}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty a_rx^r$

$\sin x=\ln(\sum_{r=0}^\infty a_rx^r)$

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$

$\cos x(\sum_{r=0}^\infty a_rx^r)=\sum_{r=1}^\infty a_rrx^{r-1}$

Expand $\cos x$ and compare the constant and the coefficients of $x,x^2,x^3,x^4$ to find $a_r,0\le r\le4$

Answer (score 0):

Let
\begin{equation*}
D(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty d_kx^k
\end{equation*}
be a power series expansion. Then the function $E(x)=e^{D(x)}$ has the power series expansion
\begin{equation*}
E(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e_kx^k,
\end{equation*}
where the coefficients $e_k$ for $k\in\{0\}\cup\mathbb{N}$ satisfy
\begin{align}
e_0&=e^{d_0},\\
e_k&=\frac1k\sum_{\ell=1}^k\ell d_\ell e_{k-\ell}
=\frac1k\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}(k-\ell)d_{k-\ell}e_{\ell},\quad k\in\mathbb{N},\\
e_n&=e^{d_0}\left(d_n+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{\substack{\sum_{i=0}^jm_i=n,\\ m_i\ge1, 0\le i\le j}} \prod_{i=0}^j\frac{m_id_{m_i}}{n-\sum_{q=0}^{i-1}m_q}\right), \quad n\in\mathbb{N},
\end{align}
and
\begin{equation}\label{alpha-k-power-eq}
e_k= e^{d_0}\sum_{j=1}^k\frac1{j!} \sum_{\substack{\sum_{\ell=1}^ji_\ell=k,\\ i_\ell\ge1,1\le\ell\le j}} \prod_{\ell=1}^jd_{i_\ell}, \quad k\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{equation}
These conclusions can be found in the paper [1] below.

[1] Feng Qi, Xiao-Ting Shi, and Fang-Fang Liu, *Expansions of the exponential and the logarithm of power series and applications*, Arabian Journal of Mathematics **6** (2017), no. 2, 95--108; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s40065-017-0166-4.

Consequently, we finally can obtain
$$
\exp(\sin x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}-\frac{x^5}{15}-\frac{x^6}{240}+\frac{x^7}{90}+\frac{31 x^8}{5760}+\frac{x^9}{5670}-\frac{2951 x^{10}}{3628800}-\frac{x^{11}}{3150}+\dotsm.
$$

Answer (score 0):

1. The Faa di Bruno formula can be described in terms of partial Bell polynomials $B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_{n-k+1})$ by
   \begin{equation}\label{Bruno-Bell-Polynomial}
   \frac{\textrm{d}^n}{\textrm{d} x^n}f\circ h(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nf^{(k)}(h(x)) B_{n,k}\bigl(h'(x),h''(x),\dotsc,h^{(n-k+1)}(x)\bigr).
   \end{equation}
2. The partial Bell polynomials $B_{n,k}$ satisfy
   \begin{multline}\label{bell-sin-eq}
   B_{n,k}\biggl(-\sin x,-\cos x,\sin x,\cos x,\dotsc, \cos\biggl[x+\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr]\biggr)\\
   =\frac{(-1)^k\cos^kx}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{k}{\ell}\frac{(-1)^\ell}{(2\cos x)^\ell}
   \sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n \cos\biggl[(2q-\ell)x+\frac{n\pi}2\biggr]
   \end{multline}
   and
   \begin{multline}\label{bell-sin=ans}
   B_{n,k}\biggl(\cos x,-\sin x,-\cos x,\sin x,\dotsc, \sin\biggl[x+\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr]\biggr)\\
   =\frac{(-1)^k\sin^{k}x}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{k}{\ell}\frac1{(2\sin x)^{\ell}}
   \sum_{q=0}^\ell(-1)^q\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n \cos\biggl[(2q-\ell)x+\frac{(n-\ell)\pi}2\biggr].
   \end{multline}
   Taking $x\to0$ leads to
   \begin{multline}\label{bell-sin-eq=0}
   B_{n,k}\biggl(0,-1,0,1,\dotsc, \cos\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr)\\
   =\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\biggl(\cos\frac{n\pi}2\biggr) \sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{(-1)^\ell}{2^\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}
   \sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n
   \end{multline}
   and
   \begin{multline}\label{bell-sin=ans=0}
   B_{n,k}\biggl(1,0,-1,0,\dotsc, \sin\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr)\\
   =\frac{(-1)^k}{k!2^k} \biggl[\cos\frac{(n-k)\pi}2\biggr] \sum_{q=0}^k(-1)^q\binom{k}{q}(2q-k)^n
   =\biggl[\cos\frac{(n-k)\pi}2\biggr]2^{n-k}S_{-k/2}(n,k),
   \end{multline}
   where
   \begin{equation*}%\label{S(n,k,x)-satisfy-eq}
   S_r(n,k)=\frac1{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}(r+j)^n, \quad n\ge k\ge0.
   \end{equation*}
3. By virtue of some formulas above-mentioned, we have
   \begin{align}
   \frac{\textrm{d}^n\exp(\sin x)}{\textrm{d} x^n}
   &=\sum_{k=0}^n\exp(\sin x) B_{n,k}(\cos x, -\sin x, -\cos x,\sin x,\dotsc)\\
   &\to\sum_{k=0}^n B_{n,k}(1, 0, -1,0,\dotsc), \quad x\to0\\
   &=\sum_{k=0}^n \biggl[\cos\frac{(n-k)\pi}2\biggr]2^{n-k}S_{-k/2}(n,k).
   \end{align}
   Consequently, we find
   \begin{equation}
   \exp(\sin x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl(\sum_{k=0}^n \biggl[\cos\frac{(n-k)\pi}2\biggr]2^{n-k}S_{-k/2}(n,k)\Biggr)\frac{x^n}{n!}.
   \end{equation}

References

1. B.-N. Guo, D. Lim, and F. Qi, *Maclaurin's series expansions for positive integer powers of inverse (hyperbolic) sine and tangent functions, closed-form formula of specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representation of generalized logsine function*, Appl. Anal. Discrete Math. **16** (2022), in press; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM210401017G.
2. F. Qi, *Derivatives of tangent function and tangent numbers*, Appl. Math. Comput. **268** (2015), 844--858; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.06.123.
3. F. Qi and J. Gelinas, *Revisiting Bouvier's paper on tangent numbers*, Adv. Appl. Math. Sci. **16** (2017), no. 8, 275--281.
4. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *An explicit formula for derivative polynomials of the tangent function*, Acta Univ. Sapientiae Math. **9** (2017), no. 2, 348--359; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/ausm-2017-0026.
5. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Art. 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
6. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
7. F. Qi, G.-S. Wu, and B.-N. Guo, *An alternative proof of a closed formula for central factorial numbers of the second kind*, Turkish J. Anal. Number Theory **7** (2019), no. 2, 56--58; available online at https://doi.org/10.12691/tjant-7-2-5.
8. C.-F. Wei and F. Qi, *Several closed expressions for the Euler numbers*, J. Inequal. Appl. **2015**, Paper No. 219, 8 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1186/s13660-015-0738-9.
9. A.-M. Xu and G.-D. Cen, *Closed formulas for computing higher-order derivatives of functions involving exponential functions*, Appl. Math. Comput. **270** (2015), 136--141; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.08.051.
10. J.-L. Zhao, Q.-M. Luo, B.-N. Guo, and F. Qi, *Remarks on inequalities for the tangent function*, Hacet. J. Math. Stat. **41** (2012), no. 4, 499--506.

Comment: (+1) You can also find the inverse of the inverse using the Lagrange Inversion theorem which gives an expansion in terms of bell polynomials. Look in the [*Inverse Lagrange theorem article*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) right after it says “ If one can express the functions f and g in formal power series as” for this related formula

Comment: While interesting, this is *surely* over-complicated and unlikely to help the OP.

Comment: @preferred_anon Do you know any simple form or an easy method? If not, I think my answer is the best and general.

Comment: @qifeng618 I don't. I think there may have been a misunderstanding - the title of the question says to "derive the Taylor series", but the body indicates that the OP is only interested in the first four terms. It's clear to me at least that they're just solving an exercise, and they have an elementary problem with it. I think it's unlikely they would follow your derivation, and it doesn't address the actual issue they describe in their original post.

Comment: @preferred_anon Oh, the question just requires the first four terms, but I provide a general term, I do too more, sorry for my doing too more.

Comment: @qifeng618 No need to apologise! Thank you for your contribution to the site. It's not bad to provide very general answers here - my only worry in this case is that the questioner will probably not understand it (meaning your effort will be wasted).

Comment: @preferred_anon Frankly speaking, I think that your worry is too more.